# Should Flurry.onEvent be called between onStartSession and onEndSession

Tags: android, flurry

Could Flurry.onEvent be called between onStartSession and onEndSession? or could it be called "outside" of a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be called "during" a session (that is, in between calls to `onStartSession` and `onEndSession`).  Notice that `FlurryAgent.onEvent` does not take your Flurry ID as an argument, this is because it uses the same ID you provide when you call `onStartSession` earlier.